# Grabbing meta content with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Do I need to use regex here?

The content I want looks like:

```
<meta content="text I want to grab" name="description"/>
```

However, there are many objects that start with "meta content=" I want the one that ends in name="description". I'm pretty new at regex, but I thought BS would be able to handle this.

Comment: I tried what they did there and it didn't work, sadly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you were able read the HTML contents into a variable and named the variable `html`, you have to parse the HTML using beautifulsoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

Then, to search for `<meta content="text I want to grab" name="description"/>`, you have to find a tag with name `'meta'` and attribute `name='description'`:

```
def is_meta_description(tag):
    return tag.name == 'meta' and tag['name'] == 'description'

meta_tag = soup.find(is_meta_description)
```

You are trying to fetch the `content` attribute of the tag, so:

```
content = meta_tag['content']
```

---

Since it is a simple search, there is also a simpler way to find the tag:

```
meta_tag = soup.find('meta', attrs={'name': 'description'})
```

Comment: I was using the 'lxml' parser, that might have been the issue, thanks. Is there a way to do it with `page = requests.get(url) ; soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')`

Comment: Ok that worked. I swear to god I tried that and got nothing, but thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2516746 Yes, that is exactly the way to do it with requests, just use `html.parser` instead if it is html ;)

Comment: I'm using `lxml` and this did work just fine!